# Using inject only returning the first value and want the total

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ActiveRecord result and want to iterate over all the elements to return a sum. I have :

```
readings=Reading.where("user_id=? and time between ? and ?", user_id, start_of_day, end_of_day)
puts "ids: " + readings.map(&:id).to_s
sum=0
sum = readings.inject({}) do |total, element|
  total = element.value
  total
end
puts "here is the sum: #{sum}"
```

but the sum is only the first value. I know this is some silly syntax issue but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: sum is an array or hash?

Comment: should just be an int - shoot, so just trying to return a total of element.value's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try:

```
sum = readings.inject(0) do |total, element| # 0 is the initial value of `total`
  total += element.value
end
```

If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for `total`, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of `total`.  Please note that
if `readings` is an empty array, `sum` will be `nil`.

```
sum = readings.inject { |total, element| total += element.value }
```

Comment: would you say that you should always set it to 0 in the case when empty so not nil?

Comment: yes, if you don't want the sum is nil, you should set the initial value

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look up the docs for the `#inject` method. (Btw. a simplified version of the code above is `readings.pluck(:value).inject(:+)`). Inject simply iterates over a collection passing each item to the block, as well as the last returned value in the block. So it also lets you do such things as `(1..10).inject(:eat) { |action, t| t.times { __send__(action) } if __send__("needs_to_#{action}?"); what_do_i_do_after_i(action) }` (silly example, but you see it is more interesting than suming ints)